# How to Show and Hide footer(Text) when scrolling up or down?

Tags: html, css

I tried almost everything in HTML to hide footer once we scrolling down but it fails. The code I'm trying to use for is:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*replace 900px with your width*/
  width: 900px;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>This would be your footer content!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that You need to use the scrollTop() functionality like below example :

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var sroll_val = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    if(sroll_val > 50 && sroll_val < 70){
     $('.wrap').animate({opacity:0});
    }if(sroll_val > 70 && sroll_val < 90){
     $('.wrap').animate({opacity:1});
    }
})
```

```css
body{
    
}
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 90%;
opacity:1;
 }

 #footer {
  width:100%;
 }


#footer {
  position:fixed;
  width:100;
  color: white;
        bottom:0;
        background-color:pink;
  z-index:999999;
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
    <p>content</p><p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <div id="footer">
          <div class="wrap">
               <p>This would be your footer content!</p>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did everything as above code but still having a problem with  this script  `code`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> `code` whenever i put my all content goes hide

Comment: i just removed jquery and change some code in css and now its working thank you so mych for help

Comment: If you got your answer then "mark" this question so others can also take help from your query.